# Эффективность цикла while

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

На сколько эффективно использование цикла `while`, чем цикл `for` на примере данного кода (я понимаю в емкости цикла `for`, но мало ли в скорости или в чем то еще)

**Цикл `for`**

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 16, 9]
f = 1
a.sort()
for v in a:
    if str(f) in str(v):
        f += 1
    else:
        a.append(f)
        a.sort()
        print(str(a) + '\n' + str(f))
        break
```

---

**Цикл `while`**

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 16, 9]
f = 1
while f in a:
    f += 1
else:
    a.append(f)
print(str(a) + '\n' + str(f))
```

Comment: У тебя код разный

Comment: @Qwertiy Выполняет он одно и тоже. Проходит через весь список `a` и если есть недостающая цифра заполняет ее и выводит список `a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На уровне байткода цикл for отличается от цикла while только операцией создания итератора:

```
10 CALL_FUNCTION           1
12 GET_ITER
14 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
```

вместо

```
10 COMPARE_OP              0 (<)
12 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       24
```

На скорость это не влияет.

Comment: а правильность на примере этого кода как лучше было бы писать через цилк `while` ли `for`? А по скорости сравнил там где то на 1 секунду цикл `for` уступает `while`

Comment: Через for. Пример с while у вас, прямо скажем, весьма странен.

Answer (score 0):

Скорость падает:
Генераторы - - - > Цикл на основе for - - - > Цикл на основе  while. 
По Лутцу  вроде так,  если не прав поправьте.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что значит выражение `Генераторы - - - > Цикл на основе for - - - > Цикл на основе while`, но я уже написал в комментарии выше, что разница в скорости на 1 сек у цикла `while` дольше запрос идет чем у `for`